# Can not understand options pricing

Tags: options, equities

As we are seeing here http://www.theoptionsguide.com/strike-price.aspx

1. Relationship between Strike Price & Call Option Price
2. Relationship between Strike Price & Put Option Price

I do not understand these two things. Can anyone help me to understand this.

Thanks,

Comment: It is not surprise to see downvote. But it is surprise to see downvote with out any comment.  :)

Comment: I didn't vote but I believe the reason to be that this question is not on-topic here as described in the [faq].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option pricing is all about intrinsic value and time value. The intrinsic value is the difference between the strike price and the underlying market price.

1. A call is a right to buy the underlying. Therefore intrinsic value of a call is positive when the strike price is below the underlying market price. You can buy for less than the market offer.
2. A put is the right to sell the underlying. Therefore intrinsic value of a put option is positive when the strike price is above the underlying market price. You can sell for more than the market bid.